# Attribute Nonetype doesn't have have method .count()

Tags: python

When i was making a simple tic-tac-toe game i suddenly got this error in my winner() function which uses line_winner(line) to find a winner for each row column and diagonal but i don't know why it is throwing "Attribute None type doesn't have have method line.count()" error which i think it shouldn't so i'm attaching whole program so that you can test that and play that game if it works fine and help me out where i was wrong.

```
 from random import randint


def new_board():
    """Generate and return a new empty board"""
    board = [[' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', '  ', ' ']]
    return board


def square(board, row, column):
    """Return the contents of square (row, column) of board.
         The value is either 'O', 'X' or ' '
      """
    return board[row][column]


def row(board, row_num):
    """Return the given numbered row (0 - 2) of board"""
    if -1 < row_num < 3:
        return board[row_num]
    return 0


def column(board, column_num):
    """Return the given numbered column (0 - 2) of board"""
    col = []
    if -1 < column_num < 3:
        for rows in range(0, len(board)):
            col.append(board[rows][column_num])
        return col
    return 0


def diagonal(board, diagonal_selector):
    """Return the 3 element diagonal of the board selected by
           diagonal_selector, one of TOP_LEFT_BOTTOM_RIGHT or
           TOP_RIGHT_BOTTOM_LEFT
        """
    diagonals = []
    if diagonal_selector == 1:
        diagonals.append(board[0][2])
        diagonals.append(board[1][1])
        diagonals.append(board[2][0])

    elif diagonal_selector == 0:
        diagonals.append(board[0][0])
        diagonals.append(board[1][1])
        diagonals.append(board[2][2])

    else:
        return diagonals


def empty_squares(board):
    """Return a list of the empty squares in the board, each as
         a (row, column) tuple"""
    indexes = []
    for rows in range(0, len(board)):
        for col in range(0, len(board[0])):
            if square(board, rows, col) == ' ':
                indexes.append((rows, col))
    return indexes


def line_winner(line):
    """Return 'O' or 'X' if all elements in the 3-element list line
           are the same and non-blank. Otherwise return None"""
    if line.count(line[0]) == 3 and line[0] != ' ':
        return line[0]
    return None


def winner(board):
    """Return 'O' or 'X' if either of those has won the game.
         Otherwise return None. It is assumed there can be only a
         single winning line."""
    game_winner = None
    for index in range(0, len(board)):
        # Check rows
        if line_winner(row(board, index)) is not None:
            game_winner = line_winner(row(board, index))

        # check columns
        elif line_winner(column(board, index)) is not None:
            game_winner = line_winner(column(board, index))

        # check diagonals
        elif index < 2:
            if line_winner(diagonal(board, index)) is not None:
                game_winner = line_winner(diagonal(board, index))

        # final winner
    return game_winner


def game_over(board):
    """Given a board state return true iff there's a winner or
         if the game is drawn."""

    # there is a winner
    if winner(board):
        return True

    # every square is filled
    elif len(empty_squares(board)) == 0:
        return True

    return False


def game_result(board):
    """Return 'Won by O', 'Won by X' or 'Draw' according to the
           state of board. It is assume the game is over."""
    if winner(board) == 'X':
        print("Won by player X")
    elif winner(board) == 'O':
        print("Won by player O")
    else:
        print("Draw")


def make_human_move(current_player, board):
    """Given a board state and the human piece ('O' or 'X')
       ask the player for a location to play in. Repeat until a
       valid response is given. Then make the move, i.e., update
       the board by setting the chosen square to the player's piece.
    """
    if current_player == 'X':
        print("X's move")
    if current_player == 'O':
        print("O's move")
    move = input("Enter row and column [0-2] ")
    rows = int(move[0])
    col = int(move[-1])
    if -1 < int(move[0]) < 3 and -1 < int(move[-1]) < 3 and square(board, rows, col) == ' ':
        board[rows][col] = current_player
    else:
        print("Illegal move try again")
        make_human_move(current_player, board)


def play_one_turn(board, current_player, human_player):
    """Given a board state and the current
          player ('O' or 'X'), play one move"""
    if current_player == human_player:
        make_human_move(current_player, board)
    else:
        make_computer_move(current_player, board)


def other_player(player):
    """Return X if player is O else return O"""
    if player == 'X':
        return 'O'
    elif player == 'O':
        return 'X'
    return ' '


def get_O_or_X():
    """Ask the human if they want to play O or X and return their
           choice"""
    choice = input("Would you like to play O or X ?")
    if choice == 'X' or choice == 'O':
        return choice
    else:
        get_O_or_X()


def play_game(human_player, board):
    """Play until a win or a draw"""
    current_player = human_player
    while game_over(board) is False:
        display(board)
        play_one_turn(board, current_player, human_player)
        current_player = other_player(current_player)

    game_result(board)


def make_computer_move(current_player, board):
    """Given a board state and the computer piece ('O' or 'X')
       choose a square for the computer to play in and
       make the move (i.e., update the board accordingly).
    """
    candidates = empty_squares(board)
    choice = randint(0, len(candidates) - 1)
    row, column = candidates[choice]
    print("Computer plays at ({},{})".format(row, column))
    board[row][column] = current_player


def display(board):
    """Display the given board"""
    separator = '+---+---+---+'
    print(separator)
    for row in board:
        print('|', end='')
        for col in row:
            print(' {} |'.format(col), end='')
        print('\n' + separator)
    print()


def main():
    """Play a game of noughts and crosses"""
    board = new_board()
    human_player = get_O_or_X()
    try:
        play_game(human_player, board)
        display(board)
    except ValueError:
        print("The program has encountered an error and needs to die. Bye.")


main()
```

Comment: `diagonal()` doesn't return anything in the `if` or `elif` blocks.

Comment: And `row()` and `column()` can return `0`, which also doesn't have a `count()` method.

Comment: @Barmar how rows and column would be zero it is zero only when my index is -1 or 3 and for the diagonals how would i check that it has winner on the diagonals

Answer (score 1):

`diagonal()` doesn't return the `diagonals` list when `diagonal_selector` is `1` or `2`. The `return diagonals` statement should not be in `else:`, it should be done always.

```
def diagonal(board, diagonal_selector):
    """Return the 3 element diagonal of the board selected by
           diagonal_selector, one of TOP_LEFT_BOTTOM_RIGHT or
           TOP_RIGHT_BOTTOM_LEFT
        """
    diagonals = []
    if diagonal_selector == 1:
        diagonals.append(board[0][2])
        diagonals.append(board[1][1])
        diagonals.append(board[2][0])

    elif diagonal_selector == 0:
        diagonals.append(board[0][0])
        diagonals.append(board[1][1])
        diagonals.append(board[2][2])

    return diagonals
```